# Multiple instances of a method?

Tags: objective-c, methods, multiple-instances

The following code renders a zombie with interchangeable coordinates. The only issue is that I have to duplicate the code and create new coordinate variables myself for each zombie. Is there any way I can create copies of the variables so I only have to have one method for multiple zombies verses three methods and three separate variables for three zombies?

```
int zombieyCord;
int zombiexCord;

    -(void)renderZombie
{
    NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path setLineWidth:4];
    NSPoint center = {zombieyCord,zombiexCord};
    [path moveToPoint: center];
    [path appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:center 
                                     radius:5
                                 startAngle:0 
                                   endAngle:360]; 
    [[NSColor greenColor] set];
    [path fill];
    [[NSColor greenColor] set];
    [path stroke];

}
```

***Edit***:

The spawning is great and works perfectly, but I want the zombies to move properly. Before, the code was that the method was called upon the player moving. This no longer works because I have to call an integer in the method.

```
+(void)entityZombie:(int)zombiexCord andY:(int)zombieyCord
{
    /* Handle Zombie Movement*/
    if (xcord != zombiexCord || ycord != zombieyCord)
    {
        if (xcord > zombiexCord){zombiexCord=zombiexCord+1;}
        if (xcord < zombiexCord){zombiexCord=zombiexCord-1;}
        if (ycord < zombieyCord){zombieyCord=zombieyCord-1;}
        if (ycord > zombieyCord){zombieyCord=zombieyCord+1;}

        /* Handle Zombie Render*/

        NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:4];
        NSPoint center = {zombieyCord,zombiexCord};
        [path moveToPoint: center];
        [path appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:center 
                                         radius:5
                                     startAngle:0 
                                       endAngle:360]; 
        [[NSColor greenColor] set];
        [path fill];
        [[NSColor greenColor] set];
        [path stroke];

    }
}
```

Player movement handling just involves rendering the player then [Entity entityZombie];
But as said above, no longer works.

Comment: Am I right in the assumption that `{xcord, ycord}` are your player's coordinates and you want your zombies to move one step towards your player on every iteration and then get rendered at the new position?

Comment: @Regexident so how do I do this?

Comment: In that case you should split up movement of zombies and rendering into separate methods. And you should probably refactor your code and create a zombie class with an NSPoint as an instance variable for its coordinates. The Zombie class would then get a - (void)moveTowardsPlayerAt:(NSPoint)playerCoords; and a - (void)draw; method. This would lead us far away from your initial question though and be better suited for a new question on a "simple human vs. zombies game controller". I'm heading to bed now, so I just dumped some sample code here: http://pastie.org/private/utesja0hf9poecidegj4ea :)

Comment: @evdude100: It might be a good idea to open a question asking for a basic "simple human vs. zombies game controller design", so the (hopefully) useful code is not buried in the pastie link, but gets good exposure. Drop me a line/link here for the question then, once it's up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(void)renderZombieWithX:(int)xCoord andY:(int)yCoord {
    NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path setLineWidth:4];
    NSPoint center = {xCoord,yCoord};
    [path moveToPoint: center];
    [path appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:center 
                                     radius:5
                                 startAngle:0 
                                   endAngle:360]; 
    [[NSColor greenColor] set];
    [path fill];
    [[NSColor greenColor] set];
    [path stroke];
}
```

Call it like this:

```
[self renderZombieWithX:10 andY:20];
[self renderZombieWithX:13 andY:37];
//...
```

Further more there is a [dedicated function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakePoint) for creating NSPoints:

```
NSPoint center = NSMakePoint(xCoord, yCoord);
```

which you might want to use in favor of:

```
NSPoint center = {xCoord,yCoord};
```

(see one of my answer's comments on why)

---

If performance is critical a cached approach like the following might bring performance gain:

```
static NSImage *sharedZombieStamp;
- (NSImage *)sharedZombie    {
    @synchronized(sharedZombieStamp) {
        if (!sharedZombieStamp) {
            CGFloat lineWidth = 4.0;
            CGFloat radius = 5.0;
            sharedZombieStamp = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize((lineWidth + radius) * 2, (lineWidth + radius) * 2];

            [zombieImage lockFocus];
            NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
            [path setLineWidth:4];
            NSPoint center = NSMakePoint(lineWidth + radius, lineWidth + radius);
            [path moveToPoint: center];
            [path appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:center 
                                             radius:radius
                                         startAngle:0 
                                           endAngle:360]; 
            [[NSColor greenColor] set];
            [path fill];
            [[NSColor greenColor] set];
            [path stroke];
            [zombieImage unlockFocus];
        }
    }
    return sharedZombieStamp;
}

-(void)renderZombieWithX:(int)xCoord andY:(int)yCoord {
    NSImage *zombie = [self sharedZombie];
    NSSize zombieSize = [zombie size];
    [zombie drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(xCoord - zombieSize.width / 2, yCoord - zombieSize.height / 2)
               fromRect:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, zombieSize.width, zombieSize.height)
              operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
               fraction:1.0];
}
```

This code is just out of my head though. Went thru no testing, whatsoever. Use with caution ;)

Comment: No, you call it like so: `[self renderZombieWithX:10 andY:20];`, as stated right in my answer ;)

Comment: If you're about to render hundreds if not thousands of zombies at a time you might want to try using one shared instance of NSBezierpath and simply move it via NSAffineTransform for each coordinate to gain performance by not having to initialize the same shape over and over again. Or render it to an NSImage which you the  just stamp at each given coordinate. Drawing images is often faster than drawing complex paths. Yours isn't complex, but it's still worth keeping in mind if performance is critical.

Comment: If I knew what you were saying I would. :-)

Comment: Note that there’s no actual benefit in using `NSMakePoint()` instead of the `struct` initialiser.

Comment: I added a rough prototype of how a cached approach might look like. Especially with complex bezier shapes (several dozens of points or more and crossing lines) drawing gets quite exhaustive. Thus if you're not changing the paths shape in any way it's a good idea to then just make one instance, draw it to an in-memory NSImage and then just stamp that over and over again. Drawing images repeatedly is usually way faster than drawing their original paths repeatedly.

Comment: @Bavarious: Well, technically that's absolutely right. But by using `NSMakePoint()` you're introducing encapsulation to how NSPoint is implemented, making your own code agnostic to NSPoint's internals, which might change (unlikely, but possible). If Apple was to change the struct's field order one day, then OP's code would break. With `NSMakePoint()` it wouldn't. (Heh, just noticed OP got x and y mixed up in his/her code anyway. It's always x before y. :P)

Comment: Apple wouldn’t change the layout of that `struct` because if they did so then **every program using it would need to be recompiled**. It is a `struct`, hence access to its members is replaced by offsets in compiled code, which makes it completely dependent on the internal layout of the `struct`. Encapsulation is an alien concept when talking about `structs`, I’m afraid.

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't thought about that. Then this begs the question though, why Apple appears to always use the convenience functions? NSMakeRect, NSMakePoint, NSMakeSize, you name it. Is there any official documentation on this? Now you got me curious ;)

Comment: Probably because declarators in `struct` initialisers are C99 only and NeXTSTEP predates C99.

Comment: @Regexident how then do I pass xCoord to another method?

Comment: @evdude100 Don't quite get your question? You pass it as argument. Just the way you did in the first place: `[self otherMethod:xCoord]`

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more specific question. Thanks!